# Two Local notifications Not Firing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I'm implementing local notification in my app. In a screen, i placed two textfield, with time.  For example,the first textfield having 2.44 pm and 2nd textfield having 2.45pm . The first textfield 's time local notification is not firing on 2.44 pm. but 2.45pm notification is firing correctly. And, 2.44pm notification displaying with 2.45 pm.

```
// viewcontroller.m file

Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls != nil)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

        UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
        notif.fireDate = [datePicker date];
        notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        {
            if ([MorningTimelbl.text length]>0)
            {
                notif.fireDate = [datePicker date];
                notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
                notif.alertBody = @"It's time to take your eye drops";
                notif.alertAction = @"Morning Notification";
                notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;


                notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
                notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
                NSDictionary *mornDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:MorningTimelbl.text
                                                                     forKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
                notif.userInfo = mornDict;
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
            }
            if ([LunchTimelbl.text length]>0)
            {
                notif.fireDate = [datePicker date];
                notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
                notif.alertBody = @"It's time to take your eye drops";
                notif.alertAction = @"Lunch Notification";
                notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
                notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
                notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
                NSDictionary *lunchDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:LunchTimelbl.text
                                                                     forKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
                notif.userInfo = lunchDict;                
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
            }
}

//appdelegate.m

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder"
                                                        message:notification.alertBody
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
    // Set icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

where i did mistake? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you set both notification notif.fireDate same that's problem.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. wait i'll check now

Comment: it's ok...check my answer @Ramdy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change as per you want:

FOR MorningTimelbl.text

- `notif.fireDate = Morningtime-date;`// set date as you want at Morningtime-date

FOR next(second-Notification) LunchTimelbl.text

- `notif.fireDate = LunchTime-date;`// set date as you want at LunchTime-date

Comment: But, fireDate is NSDate Type. So, need to convert morningTimelbl.text value to NSDate type.

Comment: @Ramdy yes there have to set different nsdate.

Comment: Y don't u give Upvote for my Question. Because of less reputation i cant give upvote for you  answer.